# Python: change "- hrs - min - sec' string into minutes decimal

Tags: python, list, csv, time

I am currently working on a project in Python (had to self-teach myself Python, still currently learning) that takes data from a csv file given to me.

I am currently stuck on how I would loop through the list to translate a string from a list such as "2 hrs 5 min 15 sec" into a decimal and saves it as another list/array.

I know about H:M:S, but in some areas of the list, it is just "8 min 4 sec", so it varies from having an hour count to just having minutes and seconds.

Comment: what do you mean decimal 2:05:15, is this what you want for "2 hrs 5 min 15 sec"  and 0:08:04 for  "8 min 4 sec"?

Comment: No, I mean decimal as in change '2 hrs 5 min 15 sec" to the calculated total of minutes in decimal form. For example, "8 min 4 sec" would be 8.0666.

Comment: You said you wanted minutes, not seconds...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options to parse these time strings. Here is one way to do it (probably not the most short one, but an easy to understand) - using [`time.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to load the time string by trial and error using 3 different formats:

```
import time
from datetime import timedelta


def get_seconds(item):
    try:
        x = time.strptime(item, '%H hrs %M min %S sec')
    except ValueError:
        try:
            x = time.strptime(item, '%M min %S sec')
        except ValueError:
            x = time.strptime(item, '%S sec')
    return timedelta(hours=x.tm_hour, minutes=x.tm_min, seconds=x.tm_sec).total_seconds()

l = [
    "2 hrs 5 min 15 sec",
    "8 min 4 sec",
    "2 sec"
]

for item in l:
    print(get_seconds(item))
```

Prints the total number of seconds for every time string:

```
7515.0
484.0
2.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Function :

```
def hms_to_mins(t):
    h, m, s = [int(i) for i in t.split(' ')]
    return float(60*h + m + (s/60))

hms_to_mins('5 30 0')
```

Output: `330.0`

You may add few more things to validate input & check that there are 3 inputs(hrs, mins & secs).

If you want to give the input as "5hrs 30mins 2sec" and run, in the above code just use this(instead of `hms_to_mins('5 30 0')`):

```
import re
t=' '.join(re.findall('\d+', s))
hms_to_mins(t)
```

**So the code would be:**

```
import re

def hms_to_mins(t):
    h, m, s = [int(i) for i in t.split(' ')]
    return float(60*h + m + (s/60))

s='5hrs3mins0sec'  //your time string
t=(re.findall('\d+', s))
while(len(t)<3): t.append(str(0))
t=' '.join(t)

hms_to_mins(t)
```

Output : `303.0`

Comment: Just add a `float()` to the return.

Comment: @Merlin I think your query is answered now.

Comment: @AniMenon, using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. +1

Comment: @Merlin I have specifically mentioned *You may add few more things to validate input & check that there are 3 inputs(hrs, mins & secs).*

Comment: @AniMenon, OP gave you 2 examples- your answer should at least work on those examples.

Comment: @Merlin That's a simple thing, anyway added it to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def str2dig(s):
      nline = s.split(' ')
      if len(nline) == 6:
          minutes = int(nline[0])*60+int(nline[2])+ float(nline[4])/60
      elif len(nline) == 4:
          minutes = int(nline[0]) + float(nline[2])/60
      else:
          minutes = float(nline[0])/60
      return round(minutes,2)


s = '2 hrs 5 min 15 sec'
print str2dig(s)
s = '8 min 4 sec'
print str2dig(s)

ll      = ['2 hrs 5 min 15 sec', '8 min 4 sec']
newtime = [ str2dig(s) for s in ll ]  
print newtime
#[125.25, 8.07]
```

Comment: who is down voting? There are no imports and pythonic??

Comment: Not sure either, weird downvotes happened in this topic.